# GradlePluginKotlinVersion inadequate?

Tags: kotlin, cordova-android

When I try to use a specific Kotlin version for cordova-android 9.1.0, I get error messages like:

```
Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.1.15.
```

That results from using:

```
<preference name="GradlePluginKotlinVersion" value="1.6.0" />
```

If I manually replace the 1.3.50 ext.kotlin_version values with 1.6.0 in the build.gradle files, then my project starts building successfully.

How can I make the build work, with my desired Kotlin version, without having to make this edit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem on Cordova 9 and wasn't able to resolve it since Cordova 9 has kotlin v 1.3.50 hardcoded in the `build.gradle` file.

So I upgraded to Cordova 10.1.0 and the issue was solved.

```
cordova platform remove android
cordova platform add android@10.1.0
```

Comment: Thx, not the answer I was looking for, but it seems to be the only option; this bug report has the same resolution: https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/issues/1235

Comment: Tried asking for it explicitly, no dice:
https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/issues/1383

Comment: Fortunately, it's not an issue for me, by the whole approach by the Cordova team really sux. `feel free to fork cordova-android yourself to backport a patch to cordova-android@9 if this is a blocking issue` comment is really dissapointing.